# conda env create -f tf14.yml - ResolvePackageNotFound

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to run the code from this repository https://github.com/thanard/causal-infogan. The instructions to install the python environment are as follows

Create a python environment and install dependencies: `conda env create -f tf14.yml`

Activate the environment: `source activate tf14`

However, I get the following error message when running `conda env create -f tf14.yml`
inside the root directory.

```
(base) kong@kong-Standard:~/causal-infogan$ conda env create -f tf14.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - pycparser==2.18=py35_0
  - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
  - markupsafe==0.23=py35_2
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py35_0
  - libgcc==5.2.0=0
  - libpng==1.6.27=0
  - ipython==5.1.0=py35_0
  - libgpuarray==0.6.2=0
  - pillow==4.2.1=py35_0
  - pbr==1.10.0=py35_0
  - cffi==1.10.0=py35_0
  - glib==2.43.0=1
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
  - fontconfig==2.12.1=3
  - libtiff==4.0.6=3
  - libxcb==1.12=0
  - dbus==1.10.10=0
  - path.py==8.2.1=py35_0
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0
  - pygments==2.1.3=py35_0
  - libxml2==2.9.2=0
  - openblas==0.2.19=0
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
  - llvmlite==0.16.0=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.3=py35_0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_0
  - pytz==2016.7=py35_0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - readline==6.2=2
  - ipykernel==4.5.0=py35_0
  - jupyter_core==4.2.0=py35_0
  - notebook==4.2.3=py35_0
  - python==3.5.2=0
  - libffi==3.2.1=0
  - mkl-service==1.1.2=py35_3
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py35_0
  - werkzeug==0.11.11=py35_0
  - pandas==0.20.1=np112py35_0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np112py35_0
  - mako==1.0.4=py35_0
  - seaborn==0.7.1=py35_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - nbformat==4.1.0=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=5
  - jupyter_client==4.4.0=py35_0
  - scipy==0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - itsdangerous==0.24=py35_0
  - flask==0.11.1=py35_0
  - jbig==2.1=0
  - numba==0.31.0=np112py35_0
  - tornado==4.4.2=py35_0
  - libiconv==1.14=0
  - decorator==4.0.10=py35_0
  - traitlets==4.3.1=py35_0
  - libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - entrypoints==0.2.2=py35_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - pyzmq==15.4.0=py35_0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - nomkl==1.0=0
  - zeromq==4.1.4=0
  - jsonschema==2.5.1=py35_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - mkl==2017.0.1=0
  - hdf5==1.8.17=1
  - networkx==1.11=py35_0
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py35_0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
  - libsodium==1.0.10=0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - olefile==0.44=py35_0
  - jinja2==2.8=py35_1
  - boto==2.48.0=py35_0
  - openssl==1.0.2j=0
  - nbconvert==4.2.0=py35_0
  - numexpr==2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - pexpect==4.0.1=py35_0
  - mock==2.0.0=py35_0
  - numpy==1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
  - expat==2.1.0=0
  - freetype==2.5.5=1
  - ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py35_0
  - terminado==0.6=py35_0
  - pygpu==0.6.2=py35_0
  - python-dateutil==2.5.3=py35_0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.3=py35_0
  - icu==54.1=0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - jpeg==9b=0
  - xz==5.2.2=0
```

The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154899/resolvepackagenotfound-create-env-using-conda-and-yml-file-on-macos/58160918 says to move the packages under the `pip` section. Is there an automatic way to resolve this instead of manually moving things around everytime a similar issue pops up?